# Returning information based on form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

a question (very much a beginner's one), I am trying to do the following: a user picks his choices from 3 dropdowns within a form and the values are passed to another file

```
action="process.php" method="post"
```

in which few operations are done with it as well as an API call is made with an external database. This part is okay and I get a return information, however, what I would like is to return the result to the page where the form is located (specifically, there would be a modal box visible after the form submission with the information from that external database and based on their entry). So here I have one problem which is a redirection to process.php and the other one how to use the variables which are their without the page refresh?

The other thing is related to the API call, it's basically all good and I get a json which seems to be not good. When I do

```
json_decode($data)
```

i get nothing. When I try some of the tools for json validation I can see that there are errors in form of undefined characters that make new lines (breaks) that probably also break the json_decode. Does someone have experience with this kind of problem?

Comment: If the form submission should redisplay the process page, is it really necessary to pass the values to another file? Why can't process.php implement the necessary functionality? What is the value of $data? Did you write the API call or is it a 3rd party API?

Comment: why don't you use ajax for that ? it will be simple with ajax, just wait for the response and display it.

Comment: @redbirdo it isn't necessary to pass it on to another file, but if I do it on the page where form is located I still get a page refresh and all I want is just to stay the way it is and just display the modal box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just reply to this to update that I have solved it eventually. The problem was that the JSON I was retrieving from the API was too big i.e had too many levels.

This solved the issue:

```
$decoded_json = json_decode($data, true, 512);
```